# XCTestCase does not se project classes

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

Somehow my `XCtestCase` class does not have access to classes in my project. Is there -and if yes, where to check it- a way to check whether the test files are linked with the project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the file you want to import or use in your Test Case.
On the Identity Inspector, Check the Target Membership section.
Check whether your Tests target is selected there, else select it.

[image: Identity Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the project settings whether you have Tests target

[image]